# Elsa Workflow Integration in Asp.net Boilerplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, aspnetboilerplate, elsa-workflows

I am trying to integrate Elsa workflow in my .net core application. Following error comes.

```
ERROR 2021-01-22 14:34:08,632 [15   ] nostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware - An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.


Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.RelationalModelAnnotations' from assembly 
'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=3.1.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.RelationalPropertyAnnotations' from assembly 
'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=3.1.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.RelationalFullAnnotationNames' from assembly 
'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=3.1.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
```

.net core Version :- 3.1

Comment: What version of Elsa did you reference?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that if you use .NET Core 3.1, you reference Elsa 1.4, not Elsa 1.5 or Elsa 2.0.
When using .NET 5, make sure you reference Elsa 1.5 or higher.